# Wordpress website redirection to another domain

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect, spam-prevention

Hi for the past two months I have been facing backdoor redirection spam on my website. Whenever a new user enters the website and clicks on any new element, it redirects the user to a spam link :- "https://yourbigexplosivewin.life/?u=7mkpd0d&o=ex5whk5" or "http://blenderelements.com/"
Upon searching further I came across the attached screenshot but I am unable to figure out its source or where it is located in my file manager.

I researched about it and saw some similar posts about hello.php spam but I have deleted the plugin 2 months back only but with no luck as the spam is still there on the website. I have tried using the wordfence and sucuri security plugin, but still facing the same issue. I will be attaching a screenshot of wordfence security scan, it shows the actual path of vulnerable files, but when I visited the path I found nothing.
[wordfence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XRx9.jpg)

Comment: Could it be somewhere in the .htaccess?

Comment: What screenshot? Does the bad link show when you hover over the link, or just when you click on it?

Comment: No, the link does not shows on hover, it only gets redirected from our website whenever a new user try to open a page on our website from the menu or anywhere.
Our issue is exactly same like this :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65271199/how-to-find-the-source-of-unknown-script-includes-in-header

Comment: Your website files are infected. Removing malware from deeply infected wordpress environment is not easy and does not have a fixed solution. Infact wordfence themselves provides paid services to do a full cleanup. I would suggest reverting to a working backup or doing a manual cleanup.

Comment: I have tried doing mannual cleanup of Wordpress from the cpanel and also tried to restore my website from one of my previous backup, but the issue is still on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Problematic Plugin (WP Rocket), It should be fixed.

Because Wordfence Said,

This File contains suspected malware URL: wp-content/cache/wp-
rocket/**********/product/calacatta-viola/index-https-
webp.html

Also Delete **wp-content/cache/wp-
rocket/** folder from file manger.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you´ll have to remove the post from the database as it has been injected into the post table. you can use mysql search function to search the url. I also had same issue and deleting the links from the database helped. but ensure you make a backup of your database incase something wrong happened.

Comment: I am not able to find the exact post, can you please assist me regarding this?

Comment: you can do a global search from the database with the url. do you have a small knowledge about querying a database ?